# Curved Text around an arc or circle in canvas using Fabric.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

I am currently working in Fabric JS.
I am drawing text in Canvas using Fabric JS.
Here is my code:

```
text = new fabric.IText('Lorem Ipsum', {
    fill: 'black',
    fontSize: 50,
    id: 'text'
});

canvas.add(text);
canvas.centerObject(text);
canvas.requestRenderAll();
```

How can I curve this text around an Arc or Circle like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

And also, how can I change the Arc value of text by using a Range Input?